# I can't access a specific port on localhost other than port 80, using my phone

Tags: .net, angular, localhost, firewall, windows-firewall

On my Windows 10 desktop, I'm running a site on localhost, and another site (Angular 2 if that matters) on localhost:51317.

I'm trying to test it on my phone.

On my iPhone, connected to the same wifi as my computer, I go to my IP address in Safari (example 1.2.3.4), and it successfully loads port 80.

But if I go to 1.2.3.4:51317, I get no response. Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding. But on my computer, localhost:51317 works).

What I've tried:

1. In Windows Firewall, I added an Inbound Rule for port 51317 (TCP) (Port, 51317, Allow the connection, Apply to: Domain, Private, Public)
2. Added an Inbound Rule for UDP 51317 as well
3. I disabled Windows Firewall

None of these let my phone access 51317, but I could access port 80.

If it's relevant, that site is Angular 2 on .NET backend.

Comment: What wifi router are you working with? Perhaps the router itself needs to be set up to allow this access.

Comment: Not sure, it's at a shared office building. I guess I'd have to ask them to open up ports for me?

Comment: On the computer, use netstat (PC equivalent of `netstat -an | grep LISTEN`) to verify that you are listening on the ethernet interface. If you're just listening on localhost (127.0.0.1) then connections will only be possible from the computer itself. If you see an interface `0.0.0.0` then that means 'all interfaces' and includes ethernet.